# Prolog: How to create all possible combinations without repetitions

Tags: prolog

I am trying to create a predicate that finds all possible combinations without repeating same numbers. I tried using permutation predicate, but it found duplicated lists. For example:

```
permutation([0,1,1], L).
L = [0,1,1];
L = [0,1,1];
L = [1,0,1];
L = [1,1,0];
L = [1,0,1];
L = [1,1,0];
```

What I need:

```
newPermutation([0,1,1], L).
L = [0,1,1];
L = [1,0,1];
L = [1,1,0];
```

Can someone please help me with that? Thanks a lot...

Comment: `?- distinct(permutation([1,1,0],L)).`

Comment: I want to help but you should first do the footwork and figure out what you really need. Start by reading the [Wikipedia page about "permutation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). You don't have a set, you have a list, representing possibly a multiset, and anyway you say that you need "combinations without repetitions" but then you use a predicate called "permutation".

Comment: @GuyCoder: `distinct(permutation([X,Y],Xs)), X = Y` still gives a redundant answer.

Answer (score 4):

The repetition-free permutations of `[0, 1, 1]` are the possible interleavings of the lists `[0]` and `[1, 1]`:

```
?- list_list_interleaving([0], [1, 1], Interleaving).
Interleaving = [0, 1, 1] ;
Interleaving = [1, 0, 1] ;
Interleaving = [1, 1, 0] ;
false.
```

We can define this as:

```
list_list_interleaving([], Ys, Ys).
list_list_interleaving([X | Xs], [], [X | Xs]).
list_list_interleaving([X | Xs], [Y | Ys], [X | Interleaving]) :-
    list_list_interleaving(Xs, [Y | Ys], Interleaving).
list_list_interleaving([X | Xs], [Y | Ys], [Y | Interleaving]) :-
    list_list_interleaving([X | Xs], Ys, Interleaving).
```

For more than two distinct elements, we need the ability to interleave all the lists in a list:

```
lists_interleaving([Xs], Xs).
lists_interleaving([Xs, Ys | Lists], Interleaving) :-
    lists_interleaving([Ys | Lists], Interleaving0),
    list_list_interleaving(Xs, Interleaving0, Interleaving).
```

For example:

```
?- lists_interleaving([[a, a], [b], [c, c]], Interleaving).
Interleaving = [a, a, b, c, c] ;
Interleaving = [a, b, a, c, c] ;
Interleaving = [a, b, c, a, c] ;
Interleaving = [a, b, c, c, a] ;
Interleaving = [b, a, a, c, c] ;
Interleaving = [b, a, c, a, c] ;
Interleaving = [b, a, c, c, a] ;
Interleaving = [b, c, a, a, c] ;
Interleaving = [b, c, a, c, a] ;
Interleaving = [b, c, c, a, a] ;
Interleaving = [a, a, c, b, c] ;
Interleaving = [a, c, a, b, c] ;
Interleaving = [a, c, b, a, c] ;
Interleaving = [a, c, b, c, a] ;
Interleaving = [c, a, a, b, c] ;
Interleaving = [c, a, b, a, c] ;
Interleaving = [c, a, b, c, a] ;
Interleaving = [c, b, a, a, c] ;
Interleaving = [c, b, a, c, a] ;
Interleaving = [c, b, c, a, a] ;
Interleaving = [a, a, c, c, b] ;
Interleaving = [a, c, a, c, b] ;
Interleaving = [a, c, c, a, b] ;
Interleaving = [a, c, c, b, a] ;
Interleaving = [c, a, a, c, b] ;
Interleaving = [c, a, c, a, b] ;
Interleaving = [c, a, c, b, a] ;
Interleaving = [c, c, a, a, b] ;
Interleaving = [c, c, a, b, a] ;
Interleaving = [c, c, b, a, a] ;
false.
```

The key observation here is that interleaving is not the same as just inserting elements into a list at an arbitrary position: Interleaving keeps the relative order of the elements of the lists. So the first occurrence of `a` will always precede the second occurrence of `a`. We can see this more clearly if we label the elements:

```
?- list_list_interleaving([a1, a2], [b1, b2], Interleaving).
Interleaving = [a1, a2, b1, b2] ;
Interleaving = [a1, b1, a2, b2] ;
Interleaving = [a1, b1, b2, a2] ;
Interleaving = [b1, a1, a2, b2] ;
Interleaving = [b1, a1, b2, a2] ;
Interleaving = [b1, b2, a1, a2] ;
false.
```

`a1` always precedes `a2`, `b1` always precedes `b2`.

So we can do what we need if our input is separated into such a list of lists. This is a multiset of the elements of the original list. We can compute multisets like this:

```
list_multiset([], []).
list_multiset([X | Xs], Multiset) :-
    list_multiset(Xs, Multiset0),
    (   ClassX = [X | _],
        select(ClassX, Multiset0, MultisetWithoutClassX)
    ->  Multiset = [[X | ClassX] | MultisetWithoutClassX]
    ;   Multiset = [[X] | Multiset0] ).
```

For example:

```
?- list_multiset([a, b, c, a, c], Multiset).
Multiset = [[a, a], [b], [c, c]].
```

So then the distinct permutations (combinations, whatever) are the interleavings of a list's multiset representation:

```
distinct_permutation(List, Permutation) :-
    must_be(ground, List),
    list_multiset(List, Multiset),
    lists_interleaving(Multiset, Permutation).
```

This works:

```
?- distinct_permutation([0, 1, 1], Permutation).
Permutation = [0, 1, 1] ;
Permutation = [1, 0, 1] ;
Permutation = [1, 1, 0] ;
false.
```

It's much faster than slaggo's solution, but so far only works on ground lists:

```
?- time(aggregate_all(count, distinct_permutation([1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],P), C)).
% 63,090,949 inferences, 3.958 CPU in 3.958 seconds (100% CPU, 15941609 Lips)
C = 12612600.
```

It remains to handle lists containing variables. The heavy lifting in all of this is done by `select/3`. All we need is to "just" implement a reified `select_t/4` similarly to [`memberd_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c/27358600#27358600). Unfortunately I haven't managed to do this so far. Suggestions are very welcome, or for someone to take this approach and run with it.

### Edit: And now with fully pure support for arbitrary lists

I was thinking too complicated above: `select/3` is not needed, nor any reified version of it. The above version uses `select/3` for a relation that (operationally) adds an element to a multiset: If there is already an equivalence class containing `X`, it is extended by another `X` element, whereas if there isn't such a class, a new class `[X]` is added.

But we can write this much more directly as well:

```
list_multiset([], []).
list_multiset([X | Xs], Multiset) :-
    list_multiset(Xs, Multiset0), 
    multiset_elem_inserted(Multiset0, X, Multiset).

multiset_elem_inserted([],                  X, [[X]]).
multiset_elem_inserted([[X|Xs] | Classes],  X, [[X,X|Xs] | Classes]).
multiset_elem_inserted([[Y|Ys] | Classes0], X, [[Y|Ys] | Classes]) :-
    dif(X, Y),
    multiset_elem_inserted(Classes0, X, Classes).
```

This handles variables correctly, enumerating on backtracking all possible ways of constraining any pair of terms in the list with `=/2` or `dif/2`:

```
?- list_multiset([X, Z, X, Y], Multiset).
X = Z, Z = Y,
Multiset = [[Y, Y, Y, Y]] ;
X = Y,
Multiset = [[Y, Y, Y], [Z]],
dif(Z, Y) ;
Z = Y,
Multiset = [[Y, Y], [X, X]],
dif(X, Y),
dif(X, Y) ;
X = Z,
Multiset = [[Y], [Z, Z, Z]],
dif(Z, Y),
dif(Z, Y),
dif(Z, Y) ;
Multiset = [[Y], [X, X], [Z]],
dif(X, Y),
dif(X, Y),
dif(Z, Y),
dif(Z, X) ;
false.
```

And this carries over to the distinct permutations too (we can now remove the `must_be` from `distinct_permutation`):

```
?- distinct_permutation([X, Y], Permutation).
X = Y,
Permutation = [Y, Y] ;
Permutation = [Y, X],
dif(X, Y) ;
Permutation = [X, Y],
dif(X, Y) ;
false.

?- distinct_permutation([X, Y], Permutation), X = Y.
X = Y,
Permutation = [Y, Y] ;
false.

?- distinct_permutation([X, Y], Permutation), dif(X, Y).
Permutation = [Y, X],
dif(X, Y),
dif(X, Y) ;
Permutation = [X, Y],
dif(X, Y),
dif(X, Y) ;
false.
```

Comment: s(X). A general observation: It would help a lot to produce honest instantiation errors in all those cases where you currently are unable to produce correct answers. The English "...only works on ground lists" just doesn't execute on the Prologs I have access to.

Comment: The entire answer doesn't execute on the Prologs you have access to. You must be able to read and understand the text and take out the Prolog bits that you need and use them in the intended context. Nonetheless, I added a `must_be` guard.

Comment: I have the suspicion that you could give a much better (more general) criterion, even now without any further improvement. It is so important to get it also automated because otherwise your code can only be tested by some hand-crafted test cases (where someone read the text) and not by exhaustive runs which beat by far any other testing approach.

Comment: You're right that `ground` is a bit coarse. For example, the code would work correctly for `[f(X), g(Y)]` I believe, as would `[f(X), f(X)]` -- list elements containing variables are OK if they don't unify with any other list elements introducing new bindings. Not sure I'd call that "much better", it's a somehow even more artificial criterion. Maybe you're thinking of something else.

Comment: But anyway, this is somewhat moot as I have now updated my answer with what I believe is a fully general version above. Like so often with Prolog, it's simpler than my original thinking.

Comment: Please consider the next time to produce different answers.

Answer (score 1):

For ground lists you may do what @GuyCoder suggested: `distinct(permutation([1,1,0],L)).`

For arbitrary lists you may enumerate all distinct solutions with the help of [`dif/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/search?for=dif%2F2):

```
permutation_no_dup([], []).
permutation_no_dup(L, PL):-
  same_length(L, PL),
  length(L, Len),
  numlist(1,Len, RLMax),
  reverse(RLMax, LMax),
  length(LCur, Len),
  maplist(=(1), LCur),
  permutation_no_dup(LCur, L, LMax/LCur-L, [], PL).
  
permutation_no_dup([], _, _, PL, PL).
permutation_no_dup([], _, LMax/LCur-L, PL, PL1):-
  dif(PL, PL1),
  next(LCur, LMax, NLCur),
  permutation_no_dup(NLCur, L, LMax/NLCur-L, [], PL1).
permutation_no_dup([Take|LCur], L, Info, PL, PL1):-
  nth1(Take, L, Item, L1),
  permutation_no_dup(LCur, L1, Info, [Item|PL], PL1).

next([Cur|LCur], [Max|_], [NCur|LCur]):-
  Cur < Max,
  succ(Cur, NCur).
next([Cur|LCur], [Cur|LMax], [1|NLCur]):-
  next(LCur, LMax, NLCur).

same_length([],[]).
same_length([_|Xs], [_|Ys]) :-
   same_length(Xs, Ys).
```

Sample run:

```
?- permutation_no_dup([0,1,1], L).
L = [1, 1, 0] ;
L = [1, 0, 1] ;
L = [0, 1, 1] ;
false.
?- permutation_no_dup([X,Y], L), X=Y.
X = Y,
L = [Y, Y] ;
false.
```

---

Update:

With the above code, I get this output with SWI 8.0.2 which is obviously wrong:

```
?- permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P), P=[x,y,z,z].
false.

?- P=[x,y,z,z], permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P).
P = [x, y, z, z],
Z = z ;
false.
```

but rearranging the call to `dif/2` in the second clause of `permutation_no_dup/5` so it now reads:

```
permutation_no_dup([], _, _, PL, PL).
permutation_no_dup([], _, LMax/LCur-L, PL, PL1):-
%      dif(PL, PL1),    % <-- removed dif/2 from here
  next(LCur, LMax, NLCur),
  permutation_no_dup(NLCur, L, LMax/NLCur-L, [], PL1),
  dif(PL, PL1).         % <-- Moved dif/2 to here
permutation_no_dup([Take|LCur], L, Info, PL, PL1):-
  nth1(Take, L, Item, L1),
  permutation_no_dup(LCur, L1, Info, [Item|PL], PL1).
```

Now we get:

```
?- permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P), P=[x,y,z,z].
Z = z,
P = [x, y, z, z] ;
false.

?- P=[x,y,z,z], permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P).
P = [x, y, z, z],
Z = z ;
false.
```

Comment: I forgot to put `next/3`, which gives the next item in the enumeration. And I added a clause for the corner case  `permutation_no_dup([], L).`

Comment: `permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P), P=[x,y,z,z].` fails. It should (trivially) succeed.

Comment: In SICStus it works.

Comment: In SWI 6.6.4, 7.6.4, 8.4.0 it does not work. Which version are you using? (Note that I removed the other case which failed only in 6.6.4)

Comment: I am using SWI 8.0.2. In SICStus `permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P), P=[x,y,z,z].` succeeds or fails as with my SWI version ?

Comment: @false: Rearranging the call to `dif/2` as shown in the updated answer fixes your sample. Still not sure why...

Comment: Obviously, atvs are still broken in SWI.

Comment: In SICStus `permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P), P=[x,y,z,z].` correctly succeeds, to see that this is in fact correct, just consider: `P=[x,y,z,z], permutation_no_dup([x,y,Z,Z],P)` which succeeds in SICStus but also in all versions of SWI.

Comment: Reported as [#105](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/issues/issues/105).

Comment: Fixed as [8.5.3](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/ann-swi-prolog-8-5-3/4688).