# Predicate order change causes infinite loop

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

So I've got a predicate that works for uninstantiated variables `nat_cset(N,Cs)` that relates a natural number with the counting set `Sn = {1,2,...,N}`.

```
nat_cset_(0,Acc,Acc).
nat_cset_(N,Acc,Cs) :- N #> 0, N_1 #= N - 1,  nat_cset_(N_1, [N|Acc], Cs).
nat_cset(N,Cs) :- nat_cset_(N,[],Cs).
```

One thing I've noticed is that is the following query `nat_cset(N,Cs), N = 6.` enters an infinite loop while `N = 6, nat_cset(N,Cs).` does not:

```
?- nat_cset(N,Cs), N = 6, false.
...
?- N = 6, nat_cset(N,Cs), false.
false
```

This happens because in the second query, prolog it should only look for solutions for N = 6 while in the first query, prolog will search for infinite solutions such that N = 6.

My question is, is this 'adequate' behaviour for `nat_cset/2` or is this a unwanted behaviour? I've read somewhere that the order of predicates changing the solutions makes it not monotonic and removes its purity, but at the same time I can't think of a way to make `nat_cset/2` any different.

Sorry for the noob question, a lot of the concepts are new to me and I'm still trying to process it all.

Comment: Same thing with `length(X, N), N = 6`.

Comment: Please read the recommended questions on [tag:failure-slice]. That's exactly why it exists.

Comment: I just want to hop on the train and advise against indiscriminately using constraints until you understand better Prolog without them. You should also ask yourself first and foremost: "What problem am I solving". What you are currently experiencing might be [attribute substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_substitution). In simple words, "if all you have is a hammer everything looks like a nail". Additionally, order is and has always been important, this goes all the way to [decidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The query

```
?- nat_cset(N,Cs), N = 6, false.
```

has exactly the same termination property as

```
?- nat_cset(N,Cs), false, N = 6.
```

So the goal `N = 6` has in this case no influence on termination whatsoever,<sup>1</sup>.  Only if you add it in front can it influence termination.

As [already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69623834/tree-methods-going-on-infinite-loop/69634058#comment123100258_69634058) said, rather start with programs using [successor-arithmetics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/failure-slice%2bsuccessor-arithmetics?tab=Frequent) and not `clpfd`/`clpz`.  They are much simpler and still expose the relevant properties needed to understand failure slicing.

---

<sup>1 This assumes that `N = 6` is always terminating, as it does with `clpz` in Scryer and `clpfd` in SWI. With general coroutining this is not necessarily the case. Think of `freeze(N, inf), N = 6`.</sup>